# Parsing a potential ProductId

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I need to be able to determine whether or not a particular piece of text inside a text field on my form is a ProductId.

I think I may (regrettably) need Regex for this.

Anyway, there could be any number of possible things inside a search query, and I need to determine the likeliness of something inside the field being a productid.

All our product Id's are of the following format:

> AA8678NY
>
> ONO23476
>
> OPI765.0987

And there doesn't seem to be any common format (there are over 400, 000 product id's in the database).

So basically, I guess what I'm trying to say is that any product id can be thought of as `starting with either 1 or more numbers, or letters, followed by either 1 dot or 1 or more numbers or letters, and ending with either 1 or more letters or numbers.` - And sometimes it's just a bunch of numbers.

Can we achieve something like this *without* regex?

Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: You can never be sure about parsing unless you know some more about these product ids. By current information, 3.023px or any word for that matter can be a product id.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The range of Product ID's are so varied that it's never going to be _accurate_. But parsing each search term, along with other measures will also help rule out what it is _not_ - which will eventually lead to a definite answer; either Yes, it's a Pid, or No, it's not.

Comment: Based on the definition of product id, you cannot. Ever.
"I own a motorcycle with 1000cc engine and 25.3 BHP."
Apart from "BHP." everything can be a product id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but why would you?
The Regex is actually very simple:

```
[A-Z1-9]+|([A-Z1-9]+\.[A-Z1-9]+)
```

If there is a known minimum length, replace `+` with `{n,}`

Comment: Don't you think these will parse a lot more information that just those IDs? OP says there can be anything in the search string.

Comment: @Danish - You are correct, there can be anything. But each "search term" is delimited by a special character, so when I go to parse things, i iterate over each search term, as it is in a string array

Comment: "1000cc" - how do you know this is a product id or simply cubic capacity? IMHO, no pattern can guarantee sure finding. I may be missing something here but as of now, this is my stand. Although it seems OP is happy with your pattern so have an upvote. :)

Comment: @danish: I completely agree with you. But as the OP stated, this will not be the only measure applied to a search term. Maybe in combination with the other measures it will provide a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a really simple way to do this. I'm not sure why you're so reluctant to use it. This pattern should work for you:

```
Regex productIDPattern = new Regex(@"[A-Z0-9]+\.*[A-Z0-9]+");
```

Comment: I've avoided Regex from when I first started programming (2 or 3 years ago?). It made me that scared I thought it was going to stab me. - anywho... This works well, thank you @itsme86